# Using 'ifelse' statements in R with quantitative criteria

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

New to SO. Don't kill me. I'm trying to figure out how to use 'ifelse' statements to add columns to a dataframe, based on a quantitative criteria related to a different column.

```
DTzips2[, politics := ifelse(pctr08zip > 0 & pctr08zip <= 0.33, "Liberal"),
                       ifelse(pctr08zip > 0.33 & pctr08zip <= 0.67, "Moderate"),
                              ifelse(pctr08zip > 0.67 & pctr08zip <=1, "Conservative")]
```

---

---

Error I've been getting is 'Provide either 'by' or 'keyby' but not both'. They also don't like the comma after 0.33.
Help?

Comment: Try typing `?cut`. `elif` does not exist in R.

Comment: sorry, copied the wrong code. With 'ifelse' statements now.

Comment: Ok, the parentheses are placed incorrectly, since `ifelse` takes three arguments but you chronically use `)` after only two. Anyways, I guess `cut` does it. Try typing `example(cut)` if you for some reason don't want to read the docs.

Comment: Nested `ifelse` needs to actually be **nested**. `cut` is better for this anyway, but syntactically your problem is that you have `ifelse(condition1, yes-result), ifelse(condition2, yes-result), ...`, but what you should have is `ifelse(condition, yes = yes-result, no = ifelse(condition2, yes = yes2-result, no = no2))`.

Comment: So in your case, we could simplify (assuming is between 0 and 1): `ifelse(pctr08zip <= 0.33, 'Liberal', ifelse(pctr08zip <= 0.67, 'Moderate', 'Conservative))`. Or using cut: `cut(pctr08zip, breaks = c(0, 0.33, 0.67, 1), labels = c("Liberal", "Moderate", "Conservative")`.